# Proof by Induction - multiple of?

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve this question for an Uni assignment where I have to prove by induction for what number [5^(2n)] - 1 is a multiple of. Since it's a test the possible answers are: a) 4 b) 8 c) 12 d) 24

Here's my approach:

Let:

f(n)=  [5^(2n)] - 1

Then for n=k

g(n)=f(k)=5^(2k)-1

Assuming n+1 is true, then k+1 is also true.

g(n+1)=f(k+1)=5^[2(k+1)] - 1

=25*5^(2k)-1

Writing              -1 = -25+24

```
                    =25*5^(2k)-25+24
                    =25[5^(2k)-1]+24
```

So

g(n+1)=25*f(k)+24

Let n=1

g(2)=25*24+24=24(25+1), multiple of 24.

The problem is, seems like it is also multiple of 4, 8 and 12. Which answer might be the correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is clear that if a number is a multiple of 24, then it would be a multiple of any factor of 24, hence it is a multiple of 4,8 and 12 as well. I'd say that this question is not clear enough. It is probably asking for the highest common factor for all n.

Comment: I also think so, just cannot imagine a way to figure it.
I tried using Least common multiple between the alternatives or greatest common divisor and I get 24 for the first and 4 for the second.
I even tried using n as great as 100 but still, multiple of all alternatives.

Comment: There are good question but this item in multiple answer fashion is definitely a bad one! It's like asking: *Where is Los Angeles*? a) in US b) in California c) in America d) on planet Earth. Come on!

Comment: Indeed @Raffaele! hahaha
Using HCF I get 4.

Comment: No, the HCF is 24. Because 24 divides all the $f(n)$ (in fact u can write $f(n)$ as a multiple of 24 explicitly as follows $f(n)=25^n -1 =(25-1)(25^{n-1}+25^{n-2}+...+25+1)$

Comment: Indeed @lEm, I meant the HCF for the alternatives. But for f(n) you are indeed correct.
Thanks!

Comment: @Raffaele would you Stick with 24 as well? I am very concerned about the whole quiz... its a part of my final score. Damn weird questiona.

Comment: @Paulo I think that $24$ is the answer because it implies all the other. Indeed if you say $4$ someone could say "And why not $8$?" and so on. If you say $24$ (which everybody here agree it's true) nobody can say "And why not $12$?" because it makes no sense. BTW the first number of the sequence is $24$...